# Cross platform music radio

Tags: c#, android, ios, mp3

I need to implement a cross-platform app (windows, web, android at first and then ios and even smart tv.). The app will be a simple radio streaming mp3 files from a server. I'm experienced with c# on .net platform and  unity engine, and also html+js in web. The question is what technologies should I choose. Now I'm thinking of Xamarine or something like that, but maybe there's something more suitable, please help me with your ideas.